# Problem with affectation or issue in the for Loop

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, dynamic

I created an Array with two elements, and tried a comparison of static arrays, but the incrementation of them is not working like was expected,

the expected output is `1 1` but the output gives me every time `0 1`

here is the C code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
  int b[] = {3, 2, 1};

  int *res = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));

  int sumA = 0, sumB = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    if (a[k] > b[k]) {
      printf("yes a\n");
      sumA += 1;
    } else if (a[k] < b[k]) {
      printf("yes b\n");
      sumB += 1;
    }
  }

  res[0] = sumA;
  res[1] = sumB;

  printf("%d, %d", res[0], res[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

I tried debugging the code but no solution, I think the for loop is the issue, I just need hints or permanent solution ...

Looking for you help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3}; // 1 is **indexed 0**; 2 is **indexed 1** and 3 is **indexed 2**
    int b[] = {3, 2, 1}; // 3 is **indexed 0**; 2 is **indexed 1** and 1 is **indexed 2**

int *res = malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); //memory allocation

int sumA = 0, sumB = 0; //sumA and sumB are assigned 0

//now loop is k = 0
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
//a[0] > b[0] //1 > 3 // FALSE so "NO" or 0 for if part but true for else if so it executes it
//It increments as condition is k < 2 so now k = 1;
//a[1] > b[1] //2 > 2 //Both the statements fail as you didnot specify the condition for equals so it just goes out.
//It increments k = 2 and as 2 < 2 so it fails and for loop ends.
    if (a[k] > b[k]) {
    printf("yes a\n");
    sumA += 1; //never executes
    } else if (a[k] < b[k]) {
    printf("yes b\n");
    sumB += 1; //ones executes for indexing 0 which is 1 < 3
    }
}

res[0] = sumA;
res[1] = sumB;

printf("%d, %d", res[0], res[1]);

return 0;
}

//So when res[0] is 0 its because your if statement never executed.
//so when res[1] is 1 because your else if executed once for indexing [0]
//indexing [1] failed because there is no condition for equals


//so you got the result 0 1 and not 1 1 because if statement never executed so your sumA += 1 never executed so value never changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not iterating over all the 3 valid indexes.

```c
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
```

Note: you can use `sizeof a / sizeof *a` to calculate the number of elements in the array.